# How to dump memory pages of a process?

Tags: memory, memory-management, gdb, dump

I want to dump the memory pages of a process once it finishes execution. I'm trying to use gdb for that, First I set break points at exit and _exit then I run the process inside gdb, once the process breaks I use `info proc mappings` to get the memory map of the process. it looks like the following:

```
Mapped address spaces:

          Start Addr           End Addr       Size     Offset objfile
            0x400000           0x415000    0x15000        0x0 /path/workspace/freqmine
            0x614000           0x615000     0x1000    0x14000 /path/workspace/freqmine
            0x615000           0x616000     0x1000    0x15000 /path/workspace/freqmine
            0x616000          0x129b000   0xc85000        0x0 [heap]
      0x7ffff71f4000     0x7ffff720a000    0x16000        0x0 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
      0x7ffff720a000     0x7ffff7409000   0x1ff000    0x16000 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
      0x7ffff7409000     0x7ffff740a000     0x1000    0x15000 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
      0x7ffff740a000     0x7ffff750f000   0x105000        0x0 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.19.so
      0x7ffff750f000     0x7ffff770e000   0x1ff000   0x105000 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.19.so
      0x7ffff770e000     0x7ffff770f000     0x1000   0x104000 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.19.so
      0x7ffff770f000     0x7ffff7710000     0x1000   0x105000 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.19.so
      0x7ffff7710000     0x7ffff78cb000   0x1bb000        0x0 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.19.so
      0x7ffff78cb000     0x7ffff7acb000   0x200000   0x1bb000 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.19.so
      0x7ffff7acb000     0x7ffff7acf000     0x4000   0x1bb000 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.19.so
      0x7ffff7acf000     0x7ffff7ad1000     0x2000   0x1bf000 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.19.so
      0x7ffff7ad1000     0x7ffff7ad6000     0x5000        0x0 
      0x7ffff7ad6000     0x7ffff7bbc000    0xe6000        0x0 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.19
      0x7ffff7bbc000     0x7ffff7dbb000   0x1ff000    0xe6000 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.19
      0x7ffff7dbb000     0x7ffff7dc3000     0x8000    0xe5000 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.19
      0x7ffff7dc3000     0x7ffff7dc5000     0x2000    0xed000 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.19
      0x7ffff7dc5000     0x7ffff7dda000    0x15000        0x0 
      0x7ffff7dda000     0x7ffff7dfd000    0x23000        0x0 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.19.so
      0x7ffff7fce000     0x7ffff7fd3000     0x5000        0x0 
      0x7ffff7ff7000     0x7ffff7ffa000     0x3000        0x0 
      0x7ffff7ffa000     0x7ffff7ffc000     0x2000        0x0 [vdso]
      0x7ffff7ffc000     0x7ffff7ffd000     0x1000    0x22000 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.19.so
      0x7ffff7ffd000     0x7ffff7ffe000     0x1000    0x23000 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.19.so
      0x7ffff7ffe000     0x7ffff7fff000     0x1000        0x0 
      0x7ffffffdd000     0x7ffffffff000    0x22000        0x0 [stack]
  0xffffffffff600000 0xffffffffff601000     0x1000        0x0 [vsyscall]
```

Now I have two questions, first: `getconf PAGESIZE` on my machine returns `4096` which is equal to `0x1000`, some of these memory spaces have different sizes though. how is that possible? are these spaces memory pages or just logical spaces? if these are not memory pages, how can I view the addresses of memory pages, or even directly dump memory pages to files?

my second question is the following: these addresses are supposed to be virtual addresses viewed by the program (not physical addresses), so why doesn't the program space start at 0? if I try to dump the memory starting from address 0 I get the following error: `Cannot access memory at address 0x0`. also why are there some regions in between these memory spaces that cannot be accessed (the region after the heap for example)? shouldn't the virtual space of a process be contiguous?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> some of these memory spaces have different sizes though. how is that possible?

Easy: they span multiple pages (note that all of their sizes are *multiples* of 0x1000).

> are these spaces memory pages or just logical spaces?

They are spans of one or more pages that have the same underlying mapping (the same file) and the same protections. I am not sure what exactly you call "logical spaces", but chances are you can call them that.

> these addresses are supposed to be virtual addresses viewed by the program (not physical addresses),

Correct.

> so why doesn't the program space start at 0?

Because long time ago VAX machines used to map something at address 0, and that made finding NULL pointer dereferences hard (they didn't crash). This was decided to be a *bad idea*, so later UNIX variants do *not* map zero page, and any attempt to dereference a `NULL` pointer causes `SIGSEGV`, helping you to debug your programs.